# Error retrieving device properties for persistent device

Tags: android-studio, flutter, device

While i can compile and run to an Emulator ... i cannot do so to my hard device .. but have been able to in the past. Since then i have had to reinstall both AS and Intellij and now i get this message when attempting to install on my PixelXL

```
⣾Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:
error: insufficient permissions for device
See [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] for more information
```

I have been to the link provided and followed instructions, but still no joy.

Interestingly:

```
bin $ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.11.12, on Linux, locale en_AU.UTF-8)
• Flutter version 0.11.12 at /home/jedaa/bin/flutter
• Framework revision 06ec8d3b41 (2 days ago), 2018-11-28 15:56:58 -0800
• Engine revision 72c7a75672
• Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

⣾Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:
error: insufficient permissions for device
See [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] for more information


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
• Android SDK at /home/jedaa/bin/Android/sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
• ANDROID_HOME = /home/jedaa/bin/Android/sdk
• Java binary at: /home/jedaa/bin/android-studio/jre/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
• Android Studio at /home/jedaa/bin/android-studio
• Flutter plugin version 31.1.1
• Dart plugin version 181.5656
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.3)
• IntelliJ at /opt/idea
• Flutter plugin version 31.1.4
• Dart plugin version 183.4733

[✓] VS Code (version 1.29.1)
• VS Code at /usr/share/code
• Flutter extension version 2.21.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
• HT69R0205363 • HT69R0205363 • android-arm • Android null (API null)
```

The doctor says it is connected however the hard devices is not plugged in .. and further

[image: Device is persistent]

the hard device is a permanent resident of the AS emulator connection panel .. even after removing all devices .. hard and virtual . and rebooting!!??

How can i get rid of the persistent device??

Comment: Sounds like you installed Flutter as root. That's discouraged because it's currently not well supported.

Comment: Nah ... would not have done that .. (intentionally that is!). Interesingly this morning when cold booting and running AS without a physical device attached, all appears normal ... both virutal emulators that i have installed appear and the default app works on them. However .... now plugging in  my physical device (PixelXL) the error returns. So if i did install under root i tried to 'adb root' and this is what i get:

Comment: statefulwidget $ adb root
adb: unable to connect for root: insufficient permissions for device
See [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] for more information

Comment: http://files.zimpics.org/forum/stack/PixelXL_DevOptions.png

Comment: .... and once more the device becomes a permanent member of the AS emulator connection dropbox .. whether attached to the PC or not!! I can confirm that cold booting the PC is the only way to remove it!